# Inconsistent formula returns in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I've been having problems using the following formula:

```
=INDEX(range1,MATCH(1,(A1=range2)*(B1=range3),0))
```

So I started testing pieces of it to see what wasn't working.  When I try

```
=(A1=range2)
```

and autofill it down to get

```
=(A2=range2)
=(A3=range2)
```

...

```
=(An=range2)
```

it correctly returns TRUE for the first few cells, but then erroneously returns FALSE for the remaining cells.

I've confirmed the data types are the same throughout both ranges.  I've confirmed the formula autofills correctly in all cells.  And I've confirmed the relationship should be TRUE.

What other issues could be causing this formula to evaluate inconsistently?

Comment: There are soooo many reasons this could be happening.  And there is not enough information in your question to even start guessing,  Show some data and your exact formula.

Comment: 1. On your first formula do you use Ctrl-Shift-Enter when leaving edit mode to force it to be an Array formula?  2. Instead of `=(A1=range2)` as a test, try `=COUNTIF(range2,A1)>0` as a test whether it exists in the range.

Comment: @ScottCraner I just tried Ctrl-Shift-Enter which did not change the result.

Comment: See my comment below.

Comment: @ScottCraner - I tried =COUNTIF(range2,A1)>0 which correctly returned TRUE for all cells.

Comment: Did you try the long formula in my comment?  When you used Ctrl-Shift-Enter di excel put `{}` around the formula?

Comment: You appear to have created 2 accounts. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.

Comment: It's hard for people to envision all of the ways something may not work the way you expect from reverse-engineering a somewhat obtuse formula.  Your construction isn't typical.  You will get more useful responses if you describe what you're trying to accomplish, what your formula is supposed to do, and how the results are different.

Answer (score -1):

`A1=range2` is test for equality between the content of cell A1 and the range 'range2'. Excel uses the first cell of the range for the comparison.

Now it might well be that your cell A1 is equal to the first cell in range2, but your cell A4 is not equal.